# Shorthand for add object to list if object is not null

Tags: c#, list, null, shorthand

Say I have the following in c#:

```
List<Foo> fooList = new();
Foo fooObject;
```

Does a shorthand exist for the following?

```
if(fooObject != null)
{
    fooList.Add(fooObject);
}
```

Depending on the situation in my code, `fooObject` might be null or not, but I would like to add it to the `fooList` if not null.

As far as my research goes, none of the null-coalecsing or ternary operator possibilities cover the one above.

Comment: Short answer: no. If you find yourself doing this very often, though, consider an extension method on `ICollection<T>` so you can write `fooList.AddNotNull(fooObject)` (but be sure to make the extension class `internal`, since something like this shouldn't spill over into other projects).

Comment: If `Add()` was a function then you could do it with `var x = fooObject != null ? Add(fooObject) : null;`

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen Mostert.  Your suggestion works a treat.  Appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is using an extension method

```
public class Foo 
{
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Foo> list =  new List<Foo>();
        Foo item = null;
        list.AddNotNull(item);
        item = new Foo();
        list.AddNotNull(item);
    }

    public static void AddNotNull<T>(this IList<T> list, T item) where T : class
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `list.AddNotNull(null);` won't work (since null has no type and so the type of T can't be inferred), you'd need to use something like `list.AddNotNull((Foo)null);` or `list.AddNotNull<Foo>(null);`

Comment: @Flydog57 - It works because the type `T` is inferred by the first argument (the list).